# Dart Polymer asynchronous property changes not working

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm having trouble updating **Dart Polymer** elements asynchronously.

Let's say I have a simple element that contains a label and a text input.

**The template**

```html
<polymer-element name="control-text">
    <template>
        <label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label>
        <input id="{{id}}" value="{{value}}" type="text" />
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="control-text.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**The dart file**

```dart
@CustomTag("control-text")
class ControlTextElement extends PolymerElement {

    @observable String id;

    @observable String value = "Value";

    @observable String label = "Label";

    ControlTextElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

I want to update create and update this element asynchronously from the initialization of the application with a `Timer`.

```dart
void main() {
    ControlTextElement element;

    // Add the element to a form
    initPolymer().run(() {
        element = new Element.tag("control-text");
        querySelector("#form").children.add(element);
    });

    // Function that updates the value of the element
    Function updateValue = (Timer t) {
        element.value += "Foo"; // Append "Foo" to the current value
        print(element.value);
    };

    // Start updating the value every 2 seconds  
    Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), updateValue);
}
```

The correct value is printed in the console, but the element itself is not updated. Once I change the value of the text box manually, the console will print the new value.

The observers are set up correctly, but they are not picking up the asynchronous changes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're timer is not part of your Polymer Zone, as such, it is unable to properly track its information as an Observable. See the discussion on the [depreciated web-ui mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/sX-xvMzLDU0/_F4dZE-G1lEJ).

The fix is to use an an initMethod as follows:

```dart
void main() {
    // Initialize polymer.
    initPolymer();
}

@initMethod _init() {
    ControlTextElement element;

    // Add the element to a form
    element = new Element.tag("control-text");
    querySelector("#form").children.add(element);

    // Function that updates the value of the element
    Function updateValue = (Timer t) {
        element.value += "Foo"; // Append "Foo" to the current value
        print(element.value);
    };

    // Start updating the value every 2 seconds  
    Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), updateValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer since it answered my example :). I actually need to do a manual dirty check when creating elements at random using `scheduleMicrotask(Observable.dirtyCheck);`.

Comment: or `element.deliverChanges();`.